# Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array

Tags: php, mysql, poo, mvvm

tengo el siguiente error: **Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in...** y la verdad no se muy bien por que me lo esta dando, el codigo es el siguiente: `

```
protected static $conexion;

private static function getConexion(){
    self::$conexion = Conexion::conectar();
}

private static function desconectar(){
    self::$conexion = null;
}

/**
 * Metodo que sirve para validar el login
 * @parametro    objeto    $usuario=cedula
 * @return      booleano
 */
public static function login($cedula){
    $sql = "SELECT 
            id,nombre,apellido,cedula,correo,privilegio,fecha_registro 
            FROM usuarios WHERE cedula = :cedula AND pass = :pass";

    self::getConexion();

    $resultado = self::$conexion->prepare($sql);
    $resultado->bindValue(":cedula", $cedula->getCedula());
    $resultado->bindValue(":pass", $cedula->getPass());

    $resultado->execute();


    if (count($resultado)){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Y le estoy intentando insertar los siguientes valores

```
public static function login($cedula, $pass){
    $obj_usuario = new Usuario();
    $obj_usuario->setCedula($cedula);
    $obj_usuario->setPass($pass);

    UsuarioDao::login($obj_usuario);
}
```

La verdad no se que estoy haciendo mal si alguien me pudiese ayudar o necesitase mas información se la daría, necesito resolver este problema urgente

Comment: `$resultado->execute()` va a ser `TRUE` si todo bien o `FALSE` si hubo error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema básicamente lo tienes en este segmento de tu código:

```
if (count($resultado)){
        return true;
}
```

Estás ejecutando la función **count** y esta sólo se ejecuta cuando pasas de parametro un arreglo u objeto. Lógicamente te arroja error porque el **SELECT** de tu consulta de base de datos está construido para que te devuelva como resultado sólo un registro:

```
$sql = "SELECT 
            id,nombre,apellido,cedula,correo,privilegio,fecha_registro 
            FROM usuarios WHERE cedula = :cedula AND pass = :pass";
```

Como puedes ver en el segmento anterior de código que extraje de tu descripción tu consulta siempre arrojará un sólo resultado. Observo que esta sentencia además pertenece al login de tu sitio/aplicación así que posiblemente no puedas/debas cambiarla por lo que te sugeriría eliminar entonces el `if` que mencioné en un principio o adaptarlo a esta consulta en particular. Para ello puedes utilizar la siguiente validación:

```
if ($resultado->rowCount()>0){
    return true;
}
```

Todo esto si debes mantener obligatoriamente la estructura de ese código intacta porque de no ser así, deberías tomar en cuenta el comentario de **@alomalbarez**

Espero sea de ayuda. Un saludo!

Comment: ergo `return ($resultado->execute());`, `$resultado` sigue siendo el objeto PDO, los resultados estarían en `$resultado->fetch()` y la cantidad de resultados en `$resultado->rowCount()`

Comment: @aloMalbarez Tienes razón quizás no me expliqué bien del todo. Actualizo mi respuesta para que hagan referencia a tu comentario también. Muchas gracias por la corrección

Comment: =P es que así como está `if($resultado)` va a dar true

Comment: Jaja. Ya entendí donde faltaba corregir. Disculpame leí muy por encima. Gracias @aloMalbarez ya está la validación bien realizada

Answer (score 0):

tambien puedes hacerlo de esta forma

```
$resultado -> fetch();
if(!empty($resultado["correo"])){ //con esto verifica si retorna vacio o con datos
        return true;
    }
```

yo hago eso porque el `$resultado -> rowCount()` no es compatible con algunos gestores de BD, pero tambien es valido.